# NDUnit - Delete rows based on non-primary key field value

Tags: .net, unit-testing, dbunit, ndbunit

NDbunit uses Primary key to determine what data needs to be deleted using
    Db.PerformDbOperation(DbOperationFlag.Delete)

Is there a way to delete rows based on one field value of a non-primary key field 
(e.g. delete rows where created_date = xyz)

Answer (score 0):

There is a QueryDataSet in dbunit(java version), so you could use a SQL query. I'm not sure if there is an equivalent in NDbunit.